# How to shift elastic graph by 1 hr?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a visualization on hourly basis. Data from 1 to 2 is displayed at 1 o'clock. I want it to be displayed at 2 o'clock. How can I shift the graph by 1 ?
This is the query that I'm using- 
Query -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "server-status.name.keyword": {
              "query": "https-x509",
              "type": "phrase"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "server-status.meta.current-time": {
              "gte": 1550660541174,
              "lte": 1550674941175,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "server-status.meta.current-time",
        "interval": "1h",
        "time_zone": "CST6CDT",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "4": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "server-status.type.keyword",
            "include": "http-server",
            "size": 500,
            "order": {
              "1": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "1": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "server-status.status-properties.request-rate.value",
                "script": "_value/60"
              }
            },
            "3": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "server-status.name.keyword",
                "size": 5,
                "order": {
                  "1": "desc"
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "1": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "server-status.status-properties.request-rate.value",
                    "script": "_value/60"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to shift the values by 1 hr. For example if the value is 2.0 at `2019-02-20T05:00:00.000-06:00` I want it to be displayed for `2019-02-20T06:00:00.000-06:00`

Answer (score 0):

Just a possible workaround:

Kibana display time based on browser timezone. You could set the timezone in Kibana configuration for a timezone of your interests.

**Update:**

You could use `date_range aggregation` and choose key for those buckets. You will need to generate the aggregation based on your time_range and interval.

For example:

```
"aggs": {
    "range": {
        "date_range": {
            "field": "date",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "key": "bucket1",
                "to": "2016/02/01"
              }, 
              {
                "key": "bucket2",
                "from": "2016/02/01",
                "to" : "now/d"
              }
          ]
      }
   }
}
```

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html